# Nginx conf using IF

Tags: nginx

On nginx.conf I have all desktop traffic redirected to  `/desktop/index.html` and iPhone/Android access is directed to `/index.html`.

On conf file I use "IF" and http_user_agent to determine the iphone vs desktop but I noticed using "If" is an bad way of writing.  How do I fix this so that this redirect is not using ifs.

```
set $is_sphone 0;

if ($http_user_agent ~ iPhone) {
  set $is_sphone 1;
}

if ($http_user_agent ~ Android) {
  set $is_sphone 1;
}

location /index.html {
  if ($is_sphone = 1) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
  }

  if ($is_sphone != 1) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /desktop/index.html break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to show different static index.html files to different devices, you can just point the document root to the appropriate folder, and then there would be no need to introduce additional locations or make rewrites. There are several ways to do it, but in my opinion [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) provides the easiest one.

Conceptually, the configuration would look like this:

```
map $http_user_agent $root {
    default          "/path/to/desktop/folder";

    "~*iPhone"       "/path/to/mobile/folder";
    "~*Android"      "/path/to/mobile/folder";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    ...

    index index.html;

    root $root;
}
```

Incidentally, there's nothing wrong in using "if", assuming that you know how it works and what you are doing. Avoiding useful tools just because they can cause damage when employed inappropriately is never a good idea. It would be much more prudent to read about this directive and use it to your benefit, instead of wasting time trying to find unnecessary workarounds. If you skim through [this article](http://agentzh.blogspot.ru/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html), you'll see that "if" is actually pretty logical and all possible problems related to it can be easily predicted and avoided.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to show the contents of different index.html without changing the root folder, [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) can still be useful. In this case, the configuration would look like this:

```
map $http_user_agent $index_folder {
    default          "/desktop";

    "~*iPhone"       "";
    "~*Android"      "";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    ...

    index index.html;

    location /index.html {
        try_files "${index_folder}/index.html" =404;
    }

    root /path/to/root/foler;
}
```

Comment: I just want the index.html for desktop pointed to /desktop/index.html not the whole directory.

Comment: I added an example of how it could be done in the original answer.

Comment: so the "" would be empty?

Comment: Yes, using "" here allows to assign an empty string value to the variable $index_folder if HTTP User-Agent header contains the words "iPhone" or "Android" in it.

If you don't feel comfortable with empty values for some reason,  you can replace "" with "/", then remove "/" from the try_files line and get the same result.